# Flutter/Dart - Pass Context Forward in order to Navigator.pop two Contexts back?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I need to be able to pop back two pages. As I'm creating pages on the fly using a named route wouldn't be practical. So is there a way to pass context from the original page to the destination page?

On the original page I have;

```
Navigator.push(

    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (originalcontext) => SecondRoute()),

  );
```

Then on that SecondRoute's page I have:

```
Navigator.push(

    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (originalcontext) => ThirdRoute()),

  );
```

Then on the ThirdRoute page, I'd like to pop back to the original page - bypassing the SecondRoute page.

```
Navigator.pop(originalcontext);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your `SecondRoute` like this :

```
class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget
{
 final BuildContext originalContext;
 
//other properties

SecondRoute({this.originalContext}); //Initialize other properties 

//Now use the 'originalContext'
}
```

Similarly you can define your `ThirdRoute` .

Now pass the `originalContext` ,

```
Navigator.push(

    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (originalcontext) => SecondRoute(originalContext:originalcontext)),

  );
```

**Edit** : The original question has been edited.

**First Method**:
Try this :

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst)
```

put the above code on your

```
ThirdRoute()
```

**Second Method :**
put this on your `SecondRoute()`

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => ThirdRoute()));
```

instead of plain `Navigator.push(...);`

And on your `ThirdRoute()` add this

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```

Comment: did you find it helpful ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's definitely put me in a promising direction. But still not quite there... It still pops me back just one context.

Comment: I'm guessing I was supposed to replace Navigator.pop(originalcontext) with MaterialPageRoute(builder: (originalcontext) => SecondRoute(originalContext:originalcontext)) ? That being the case, I'm guessing it's the reason I'm brought back to the unwanted middle page rather  than the original page.

Comment: Please edit your question and specify clearly what you are trying to achieve . It is not very clear from your question . Also you have written two Navigator.push(...) consecutively , I don't understand why would you need that .

Comment: The SecondRoute flashed up for a split second but otherwise, it worked. So I'm marking it as solved.

Comment: Check the second method